# TableRegistry unable to find table (namespace issue ?)

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0, autoload

I'm currently using CakePHP 3's ORM on a Slim Framework 3 project.

I used CakePHP's naming conventions for my namespaces and classes. I'm trying to get my users by accessing the users' table (location : *App\Model\Table\UsersTable.php*).

In my controller (*App\Controller\UsersController.php*), when I try :

```
$usersTable = TableRegistry::get('Users'); // NOT working
$usersTable = TableRegistry::get('Users', ['className' => \App\Model\Table\UsersTable::class]); // working
```

I have to specifically set my className (which is horrible, because I need to do this in every controller and table (for associations) classes). I don't get what I did wrong and why CakePHP is not able to retrieve these classes.

My **composer.json** is as following :

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^3.0",
        "cakephp/orm": "^3.2",
        "cakephp/validation": "^3.2",
        "cakephp/i18n": "^3.2",
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "src"
        }
    }
}
```

My project's files are located under *src/* (for example, users' table is in *src/Model/Table*).

Does anyone have an idea on how I could fix this and directly be able to use `TableRegistry::get('Users');` and being forced to add the className ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's what happens when using non-standard namespaces, and/or not configuring the base namespace option (properly), ie `App.namespace`.

Short classname resolution needs to know about the possible base namespace, otherwise it's impossible to build the proper fully qualified name, ie you must tell CakePHP about `App`

```
\Cake\Core\Configure::write('App.namespace', 'App');
```

Without this information, the short classname would only resolve to `Model\Table\UsersTable`.

- **[Cookbook > Configuration > General Configuration](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/development/configuration.html#general-configuration)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Table Objects > Configuring the Namespace to Locate ORM classes](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/table-objects.html#configuring-the-namespace-to-locate-orm-classes)**

Comment: Thanks, I didn't take a look at this part of the documentation. Works fine now !